# How `CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang|GNU"` works?

Tags: gcc, cmake, build, clang

I want to build my project using Clang as first choice, if Clang doesn't exist, and compile it by GCC, but in my practice, Cmake always choose GCC.

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8.12)
project (leptjson_test C)

if (CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang|GNU")
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -std=c99 -pedantic -fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined -Wall")
endif()

add_library(leptjson leptjson.c)
add_executable(leptjson_test test.c)
target_link_libraries(leptjson_test leptjson)
```

Comment: The expression you cite doesn't affect on the compiler choice at all. `CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID` contains identifier of the compiler which is **already selected**. `MATCHES` clause just checks this identifier for match to given **regular expression**. You may find useful documentation for that command: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html#matches.

Comment: @Tsyvarev very thanks to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How `CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang|GNU"` works?

It matches the string stored in `CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID` against extended *regex* expression `Clang|GNU`.

> I want to build my project using Clang as first choice, if Clang doesn't exist, and compile it by GCC

Looking at [CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake) set `CMAKE_C_COMPILER_LIST` to the list of your compilers. You could do:

```
cmake_minimum_required(...)
if(LEPTJSON_DEV)  # my recommendation
    set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_LIST clang gcc)
endif()
project(...)
```

I recommend to set your custom settings protected with some variable, so that other people can use your library too without your settings.